# "Safe" to drill into a wall with an electrical consumer unit on the other side?

Tags: wiring, drill

I want to add shelving to a wall. On the other side of this wall is the electrical consumer unit for my premises.

I have one of these non-contact detector pens:¹

[image: non-contact detector pen]

I won't be drilling further than about a third of the way into the wall. Just enough for a standard rawl plug. There are no sockets or switches on this side of the wall.

Can I reasonably assume that I won't be drilling into live wires? Or do consumer units often have wires penetrating deep into the wall behind them?

**EDIT: This wall has bricks in.**

(For the record, I understand how electricity works and how dangerous it is.)

---

¹ If anyone knows how to display this image smaller without actually editing the image, please edit my post to do so.

Comment: Quite safe if you watch someone else do the drilling.  Would prefer to drill only into studs, since there is suppose to be steel plates protecting wires, also stronger for holding weight.  Bays between studs are use to run wires/pipes.  I am guessing Europe since you use consumer unit.

Comment: Ho ho ho. Oh my sides, they ache so. No, I will be doing the drilling myself. Dunno about studs: this wall has bricks in.

Comment: Bricks are nice since people usually find easy ways to place wires and inside of bricks is not one of them.  If consumer unit is on other side of bricks should be okay, but I am not the one drilling.  Use smallest length of drill and screw possible for holding power.

Comment: Bricks could be cinder blocks which can have wires run in the big square holes (if not filled with concrete).

Comment: @SodAlmighty change "https://i.stack.imgur.com/17mdb.png" to "https://i.stack.imgur.com/17mdb**m**.png" and _magic_ happens! :)

Comment: @Aaron these bricks are probably normal bricks, because when I drill into them (in a different place) I get Red Martian Dust™.

Comment: You're welcome. Adding `m` as the last character of the file name will work for any image you post. Unfortunately, it does _not_ allow click-through to the original sized image. I haven't yet sorted out that one. :(

Comment: Ah ha! I figured out how to show a small image with click to embiggen! _Pats self on back, high-fives self, recognizes that probably nobody else cares!_ [Edit] the post to see what i did if you're interested.